# Refatoração de código para converter coordenadas GPS no formato DMS numa matriz

Tags: php, string, array, refatoração, geolocalização

O utilizador pode inserir as coordenadas GPS de duas formas, *Graus Decimal* ou *Graus, Minutos, Segundos*:

```
            ┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
            │ DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds) │ DD (Decimal Degree) │
┌───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Latitude  │ N 40° 11′ 48.055″               │ 40.196682           │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Longitude │ W 8° 25′ 52.134″                │ -8.431149           │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Estes valores tem que ser tratados, de forma a que fiquem num formato único para conversão entre eles, bem como para armazenamento na base de dados.

O problema está no formato DMS, onde as coordenadas introduzidas podem variar desde vários dígitos, referências diferentes para o hemisfério até aos caracteres que identificam a separação entre os valores.

Para facilitar, a introdução das coordenadas, a mesma está dividida em dois campos, Latitude e Longitude, e a introdução de espaços foi bloqueada, o que nos dá:

```
            ┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
            │ DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds) │ DD (Decimal Degree) │
┌───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Latitude  │ N40°11′48.055″                  │ 40.196682           │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┤
│ Longitude │ W8°25′52.134″                   │ -8.431149           │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

## Em funcionamento

Estou a tentar extrair o valor em graus, minutos e segundos para uma matriz, de forma a que possa converter o mesmo para o formato decimal, mas estou a achar todo o processo um pouco extenso demais e susceptível a falhas:

**Código**

Assumindo que a variável `$entity_gps` contém `N40°11'43.44" W8°25'1.31"`:

<sup>**Nota:** Os valores apesar de introduzidos separadamente, são guardados em base de dados num único campo separados por um espaço.</sup>

```php
$coordinatesArr = array(
  "lat" => array(
    "hem" => '',
    "deg" => '',
    "min" => '',
    "sec" => ''
  ),
  "lng" => array(
    "hem" => '',
    "deg" => '',
    "min" => '',
    "sec" => ''
  )
);

if ($entity_gps!='') {

  $gpsArr = explode(' ', $entity_geo->gps);

  if (is_array($gpsArr)) {

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($gpsArr as $str) {

      // Extract hemisphere
      $hemisphere = mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');

      // Validate hemisphere
      if (ctype_alpha($hemisphere)) {

        /* Store hemisphere
         */
        if ($i==0) {
          $coordinatesArr["lat"]["hem"] = $hemisphere;
        } else {
          $coordinatesArr["lng"]["hem"] = $hemisphere;
        }

        // Extract degrees
        $degree = mb_substr($str, 1, mb_strpos($str, '°')-1, 'UTF-8');

        // Validate degrees
        if (ctype_digit($degree)) {

          /* Store degrees
           */
          if ($i==0) {
            $coordinatesArr["lat"]["deg"] = $degree;
          } else {
            $coordinatesArr["lng"]["deg"] = $degree;
          }

          // Extract minutes
          $iniPos = mb_strpos($str, '°')+1;

          $minutes = mb_substr($str, $iniPos, mb_strpos($str, "'")-$iniPos, 'UTF-8');

          // Validate minutes
          if (ctype_digit($minutes)) {

            /* Store minutes
             */
            if ($i==0) {
              $coordinatesArr["lat"]["min"] = $minutes;
            } else {
              $coordinatesArr["lng"]["min"] = $minutes;
            }

            // Extract seconds
            $iniPos = mb_strpos($str, "'")+1;

            $seconds = mb_substr($str, $iniPos, mb_strpos($str, '"')-$iniPos, 'UTF-8');

            // Validate seconds
            if ($seconds!='') {

              /* Store seconds
               */
              if ($i==0) {
                $coordinatesArr["lat"]["sec"] = $seconds;
              } else {
                $coordinatesArr["lng"]["sec"] = $seconds;
              }

            } else {
              echo 'Erro ao identificar os segundos!';
            }

          } else {
            echo 'Erro ao identificar os minutos!';
          }

        } else {
          echo 'Erro ao identificar os graus!';
        }

      } else {
        echo "Erro ao identificar o hemisfério!";
      }

      $i++;
    }
  }
}
```

**Resultado:**

Resultado ao realizar um `var_dump()` à matriz `$coordinatesArr`, a mesma contém os valores conforme esperado:

```php
array(2) {
  ["lat"]=&gt;
  array(4) {
    ["hem"]=&gt;
    string(1) "N"
    ["deg"]=&gt;
    string(2) "40"
    ["min"]=&gt;
    string(2) "11"
    ["sec"]=&gt;
    string(5) "43.44"
  }
  ["lng"]=&gt;
  array(4) {
    ["hem"]=&gt;
    string(1) "W"
    ["deg"]=&gt;
    string(1) "8"
    ["min"]=&gt;
    string(2) "25"
    ["sec"]=&gt;
    string(4) "1.31"
  }
}
```

## Problema

Para além da densidade de código, que pode ser passado para funções individuais, existe toda uma série de problemas causados principalmente pelos separadores introduzidos pelo utilizador.

De igual forma, esta verificação é para ser reutilizada quando estamos a processar coordenadas GPS no formato DMS que são provenientes de outras fontes.

- Ao invés de `°` está presente um outro.
- Ao invés de `'` está presente `´` ou outro.
- Ao invés de `"` está presente `¨` ou outro.

## Pergunta

Como posso simplificar e aperfeiçoar o resultado deste código com o objectivo de converter as coordenadas GPS no formato DMS numa matriz?

Answer (score 8):

Me parece um bom caso para aplicar uma expressão regular, que já valide e capture a parte que importa da entrada, ignorando os separadores.

Pensei em algo nesta linha (mas tenho certeza de que os peritos em regex conseguem melhorar):

```regex
^([NSWE])(\d\d?).(\d\d?).(\d\d?(?:[.,]\d+)?).$
```

http://regexr.com?3856r

Em PHP você precisaria de algo como:

```php
$arr = array();
$result = preg_match('/^([NSWE])(\d\d?).(\d\d?).(\d\d?(?:[.,]\d+)?).$/u', "W8°25′52.134″", $arr);
```

Resultado em `$arr`:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => W8°25′52.134″
    [1] => W
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 25
    [4] => 52.134
)
```

http://ideone.com/VsgrRZ

Answer (score 5):

Criei uma função que acredito fazer o que você quer com menos dificuldade, baseada também em expressões regulares.

## Expressão Regular

A expressão criada foi:

```regex
([NSWE])(\\d{1,2})[^\\d](\\d{1,2})[^\\d]([\\d\\.]{1,10})[^\\d\\s]
```

Ela é composta dos seguintes trechos:

- `[NSWE]` - uma das letras 'N', 'S', 'W' ou 'E'
- `\d{1,2}` - um ou dois dígitos numéricos (0-9)
- `[^\\d]` - qualquer caractere não numérico
- `[\\d\\.]{1,10}` - 1 a 10 dígitos numéricos, incluindo também o caractere ponto final (`.`)

Basicamente a expressão como um todo pede:

1. Uma letra
2. Um caractere não numérico
3. Um número com um ou dois dígitos
4. Um caractere não numérico
5. Um número com um ou dois dígitos
6. Um caractere não numérico
7. 1 a 10 números e pontos
8. e termine com um caractere não numérico ou um espaço em branco

A parte final que recupera números com pontos poderia ser incrementada para permitir apenas um ponto. Porém, creio que esta validação deva ser feita em outro local onde uma mensagem específica sobre o formato pode ser emitida ao usuário.

Apenas para deixar o exemplo de uma expressão que apenas aceita números válidos, podemos trocar o trecho `[\\d\\.]{1,10}` por algo como `[\\d]{1,2}(?:\\.[\\d]{1,3})?`:

```regex
([NSWE])(\\d{1,2})[^\\d](\\d{1,2})[^\\d]([\\d]{1,2}(?:\\.[\\d]{1,3})?)[^\\d\\.]
```

A expressão acima não aceita entradas como `4.3.2`, `3.` ou `2..1`, pois o novo trecho possui as seguintes restrições:

- `[\\d]{1,2}` - Permite um número de 1 ou 2 dígitos
- `(?:\\.[\\d]{1,3})?` - Seguido de um ponto e um número de 1 a 3 dígitos, sendo tanto o ponto quanto o número opcionais

## Função PHP

A função ficou da seguinte forma:

```php
function get_coordinates_array($entity_gps) {
    $items = array();
    $res = preg_match_all(
        '/([NSWE])(\\d{1,2})[^\\d](\\d{1,2})[^\\d]([\\d\\.]{1,10})[^\\d\\s]/ui', 
        $entity_gps, $items, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if ($res === 2) {
        return array(
            "lat" => array_slice($items[0], 1, 4),
            "lng" => array_slice($items[1], 1, 4)
        );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Para chamá-la, basta passar as duas coordenadas numa String:

```php
$coordinatesArr = get_coordinates_array($entity_gps);
```

E o retorno será exatamente como o exemplo da pergunta:

```php
Array
(
    [lat] => Array
        (
            [0] => N
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 43.44
        )

    [lng] => Array
        (
            [0] => W
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 25
            [3] => 1.31
        )

)
```

Veja o exemplo funcional no [ideone](http://ideone.com/3Rgbd4).

Comment: @Zuul Complementei a resposta com explicações adicionais e mais um exemplo de expressão regular.

Comment: Rs faz muito tempo, mas essa expressão vc copiou do código PHP se for usada em javascript por exemplo \\ vai ser entendido como o caracter '\' `([NSWE])(\\d{1,2})[^\\d](\\d{1,2})[^\\d]([\\d\\.]{1,10})[^\\d\\s]` para `([NSWE])(\d{1,2})[^\d](\d{1,2})[^\d]([\d\.]{1,10})[^\d\s]` :)

Comment: @LeandroAmorim Isso mesmo. As barras duplicadas são necessárias para dar *escape* na String do PHP. Se for usar de alguma outra forma, tem que adequar ao contexto, considerando se é necessário o *escape* e se muda algo na a *engine* de expressões regulares. Por exemplo, nem todas as implementações suportam os limitadores de caracteres como `{1,10}`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu ainda não consigo adicionar comentários

A inteção da expressão regular é encontra padrões, e de alguma forma valida-los.

Dessa maneira seria interessante saber se a cadeia de caracteres recebidas são válidas.

```
^([NSWE])(\d\d?).(\d\d?).(\d\d?(?:[.,]\d+)?).$
```

Essa expressão regular colocando `.` (localizador de qualquer carácter) não validaria a string por exemplo `"W8251300"` ele passaria como

```
[0]=W
[1]=82
[2]=1
[3]=0
```

Essa expressão regular

```
([NSWE])(\d{1,2})[^\d](\d{1,2})[^\d]([\d\.]{1,10})[^\d\s]
```

aceitaria coisas do tipo `W8°25'1.3.1.1"`.

```
[0]=W
[1]=8
[2]=25
[3]=1.3.1.1
```

O certo seria alguma coisa perto de

```
"^([NSWE])(\d\d?)[^\d](\d\d?)[^\d](\d\d?(?:[.,]\d+)?)[^\d]$"
```

Dessa forma necessita-se que

1. O primeiro caracter seja 'N' ou 'S' ou 'W' ou 'E' `array[0]`
2. Um ou dois dígitos `array[1]`
3. Um caractere diferente de dígito
4. Um ou dois dígitos `array[2]`
5. Um caractere diferente de dígito
6. Um ou dois dígitos contendo ou não a parte decimal que necessariamente deve ser separada por '.' ou ',' essa parte decimal pode conter 1 ou N dígitos. `array[3]`

Answer (score 0):

> Existe toda uma série de problemas causados principalmente pelos separadores introduzidos pelo utilizador

Neste caso talvez fosse melhor mudar a interface de usuário para que eles não tenham tanta liberdade para digitar os valores. Eu imagino que para cada coordenada você possa ter uma série de controles: um drop-down para N/S ou W/E, e caixas de texto separadas para graus, minutos e segundos.

> De igual forma, esta verificação é para ser reutilizada quando estamos a processar coordenadas GPS no formato DMS que são provenientes de outras fontes.

Bom, nesse caso realmente um expressão regular parece ser uma boa maneira de resolver o problema. Após dar uma olhada [nessa página](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion), e com a sua informação de que os espaços foram removidos previamente, você pode usar a seguinte *regex* (com a opção *case insensitive* - `i`):

```
([nswe])?(\d{1,3})\D+(\d\d?)\D+(\d\d?(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\S?([nswe]))?
```

([regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/moudv9b))

Essa expressão regular leva em conta que a orientação (N/S/W/E) pode estar tanto no começo como no fim do texto e também que os graus podem ter até 3 números, e funciona com essas coordenadas:

```
N40°11'43.44" W8°25'1.31"
40:26:46.302N 079:58:55.903W
40°26′46″N 079°58′56″W
40d26′46″N 079d58′56″W
N40:26:46.302 W079:58:55.903
N40°26′46″ W079°58′56″
N40d26′46″ W079d58′56″
```

Answer (score 0):

Se vai lidar mais intensivamente com dados geográficos, a sugestão é usar um *framework* ou biblioteca com essas coisas já embutidas. Existem padrões e questões de precisão bem sofisticadas, mas tudo bem resolvido nas bibliotecas.

Para coisas complexas e mapas:

- Base de dados: PostgreSQL com [PostGIS](http://postgis.org/), eu uso e recomendo para tudo, qualquer cálculo ou conversão geográfica.
- Interface Javascript: [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/)

Especificos:

- [Interligar com OpenStreetMaps via PHP](https://github.com/kenguest/Services_Openstreetmap/) (ex. para dados GPS relacionados com ruas).
- [Interligar com album de fotos georeferenciadas pelo GPS, com PHP](http://phpmygpx.tuxfamily.org/) (ou [aqui](http://users.suse.com/~ke/phpmygpx/phpmygpx.html))
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode resolver seu problema:

```
<?php

function DMStoDEC($deg,$min,$sec)
{

// Converts DMS ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) 
// to decimal format longitude / latitude

    return $deg+((($min*60)+($sec))/3600);
}    

function DECtoDMS($dec)
{

// Converts decimal longitude / latitude to DMS
// ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) 

// This is the piece of code which may appear to 
// be inefficient, but to avoid issues with floating
// point math we extract the integer part and the float
// part by using a string function.

    $vars = explode(".",$dec);
    $deg = $vars[0];
    $tempma = "0.".$vars[1];

    $tempma = $tempma * 3600;
    $min = floor($tempma / 60);
    $sec = $tempma - ($min*60);

    return array("deg"=>$deg,"min"=>$min,"sec"=>$sec);
}    

?>
```

Nesse link tem um exemplo: http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_6.php